# Python, Isin, TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column `status` that shows if my DataFrame values are in my directory `test`. For example does folder `O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2010` exist in the `O:\Stack\Over\Flow` directory.

My `pl_dest` DataFrame is like so:

```
     Folder_Name_to_create
0  O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2010
1  O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2011
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

pl_dest = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Folder_Name_to_create':
        [r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2010', r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow\2011']
    }
)
test = (r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow')

pl_dest['status']  = pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create'].isin(test)
```

I receive `TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]`.

Comment: `isin` wants a list, and you gave it a string. Have you tried giving it a list? (Also, please post data/code as text, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).)

Comment: If you wanted `test` to be a tuple it needs a trailing comma `test = (r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow',)` or if you want to create a list use square brackets `test = [r'O:\Stack\Over\Flow']`

Comment: okay I made `test` a list. Code works now! although my `status` column still shows false! I think its because I need `test` to read my directory for files, not just use`O:\Stack\Over\Flow` . I am thinking `isin` may not be suitable for checking the directory `O:\Stack\Over\Flow` for `pl_dest` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pathlib` to check if directories exist using `pathlib.Path.is_dir()`. If you wrap this in a basic function you can use it with `df.apply()`

Since your dataframe has the full path you want to check, you don't need your `test` at all, I don't think.

```py
import pathlib

def my_func(test_path: str) -> bool:
    p = pathlib.Path(test_path)
    return p.is_dir()

pl_dest['status']  = pl_dest['Folder_name_to_create'].apply(my_func)
```

edit:

If your goal is really here to just create directories that are needed, you can do that without bothering to make the new column, and you should also use a `try:...except:...` rather than actually checking if they exist. You could do that like this:

```py
for folder in pl_dest['Folder_name_to_create']:
    try:
        pathlib.Path(folder).mkdir()
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
        # or in debugging you can print(f'{folder} already exists')
```

Comment: Ideal...Logic :) +1

Comment: great answer thank you. any chance you could add the logic to this , if status = false then mkdir  ?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over row & check existance

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

status=[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    path = row['Folder_Name_to_create']
    path=Path(path)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
       status.append('File_exists')
    else:
       status.append('File_not_exists')

df['status']=status
```

Expected outputs #

```
Folder_Name_to_create    status 
c://:path/example        File_exists
c://:path/example2       File_not_exists
```

> Note: Not tested...Just posting the way of execition...Try this & Let
> me know

Comment: thank you , should `df` be `pl_dest`? also how is my `test` path being picked up?

Comment: yes.....Rename accoedingly

Comment: OP's paths to check look like they are all directories, not files, so you probably want `os.path.isdir()` instead of `...isfile()`